# Which pathfinding algorithm for getting same path from A to B and B to A?

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

I need an algorithm that calculates exactly same path from A to B and from B to A in a 2D grid environment with obstacles.

I've tried A* algorithm but it calculates different paths(from A to B, and B to A) in some cases.

What these kind of algorithms are called? What are your suggestions?

Thank You

Comment: Can you "cheat"? For example, use some ordering of the coordinates and always calculate the path from min(A, B) to max(A, B), then even if the pathfinding is asymmetric it wouldn't matter because it's never asked for the "reverse" path

Comment: Can you modify the grid itself? If yes, then you could make every other cell an obstacle which doesn't come in the path from A to B, so that reverse from B to A also takes the same path.

Comment: Could you break ties in `A*` deterministically? Like always choose the leftmost, then the topmost node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all possible pairs of A and B, compute paths only for cases where A < B. Assuming A and B are a pair of co-ordinates x and y. You can compare as follows :

```
bool isALessThanB(point A, point B):
    return (A.x < B.x) or (A.x == B.x and A.y < B.y)
```

So if you need a path from B to A, just take the path from A to B and reverse it.

Answer (score 0):

If the grid is not directional, so every path from A to B is a path from B to A!

However, you can use a bi-directional search strategy. You can start search from A to B and B to A simultaneously. Then, choose a path in the middle, somewhere the path from A to B, meet a path from B to A.